# Tips for Angular 7 and CAS authentication?

Tags: angular, authentication, cas

I'm actually trying to understand exactly how all should work, actually, the logic of the authentication is this.

1) User goes to the angular application, click login and get redirect to can log in with a  URL pattern like this with my angular app as a parameter: 
cas-example.com/login?service=my-angular-app

2) If the user logs in cas redirect to the angular application with a service ticket in the URL, should be like this: my-angular-app.com/?ticket=ST-1232431

3) After I should send the ticket to my backend and if the ticket is valid, the backend send me a jwt where I can log in the user

Is this approach good? how should I implement the listener from the ticket, should I check if the redirect comes from cas and check the URL, or always check the URL?

This is the diagram flow of cas:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to be concrete, but I'll try to give you a few tips on how to handle authentication within angular.

Some tools shipped with Angular that I focus on this subject are : [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) ([an article](https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e) on it - because docs are sparse), [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor), LoadingComponent or just the typical AppComponent.

Some dependencies that also help me in this process are [ngx-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-store) and [ngxs store](https://github.com/ngxs/store). Despite the similar names they are different tools.

I'm not going to give you a fully response to your problem, but some hints :

In an authentication service you can, for example register a callback to listen for a certain cookie being modified (thanks to ngx -store). Something like this :

```
constructor(public cookiesStorageService: CookiesStorageService,
          @Inject(JWT_COOKIE_NAME) private _JWT_COOKIE_NAME: string) {
this.cookiesStorageService
  .observe(this._JWT_COOKIE_NAME)
  .subscribe((cookie: NgxStorageEvent) => this.checkIfNewToken(cookie.newValue));
```

}

Notice that above injects the cookie name for the JWT token. I find it clearer and sticks to angular principles :

```
export const JWT_COOKIE_NAME = new InjectionToken<string>('ACTUAL_JWT_COOKIE_NAME');
```

In the case above, if you pass a JWT token via cookies (not authentication header).
If you do pass a header bearing the token you could do something like intercepting the HTTP Requests. Something like :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor,
          private authService: AuthenticationService,
          @Inject(API_ENDPOINT) private _API_ENDPOINT: string) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.url.match(this._API_ENDPOINT)) {
        // this.authService.intercept$.next(req);

        const XSRFTokenHeaderName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
        const XSRFToken = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
        if (XSRFToken !== null && !req.headers.has(XSRFTokenHeaderName)) {
          req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(XSRFTokenHeaderName, XSRFToken)});
        }

        req = req.clone();

        return next.handle(req);
      } else {
        return next.handle(req).map(event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              // do something with response like sending it to an authentication service
          }         
          return event;
      });
      }
    }
  }
```

I leave the canonical example of handling X-XSRF-TOKEN.

An App initializer could do something like dispatching a Login action - or actually calling directly an authentication service method (I like using ngxs store for this kind of stuff) :

```
export function appRun(store: Store) {
  return () =>
    store
      .dispatch(new Login())
      .pipe(finalize(() => true)) // let the app handle errors after bootstrapped
      .toPromise();
    }
```

And in a Loading Component or the App Component have something like this :

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private actions$: Actions
) {}

ngOnInit() {

    this.actions$
      .pipe(ofActionErrored(Login))
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate([Routes.PUBLIC]));

    this.actions$
      .pipe(ofActionSuccessful(Logout))
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate([Routes.PUBLIC]));
 }
```

NGXS ships with the helpful handlers of action success or action errored that you can use to route somewhere (routes above are defined in an Enum).

So I'm leaving many steps out of this response (like declaring states, registering the APP_INITIALIZER, Interceptor, ...) but feel free if you figure it helps to comment for more info.
The libraries mentioned are very powerful and can help you solving your problem in different ways (or might end up just being overhead - just a service to store some state and an interceptor might be enough).
This is not very concrete, but I think it's a nice set of tips to get you going.

edit : I forgot about route guards. They can also help with authentication within angular. CanLoad (for lazy loaded modules) and CanActivate guards particularly. Something like :

```
canActivateRead(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    const perm = this.store.selectSnapshot(state => state.module.acl);
    if (perm) {
      return this.canRead(perm);
    } else {
      return this.fetchACLAndTestPermission('READ');
    }
}

private fetchACLAndTestPermission(perm: 'READ' | 'CREATE' | 'UPDATE'): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.getPermissionForACL('ACL').pipe(
      tap(permission => this.store.dispatch(new SetMainACL({ permission }))),
      map(perm => this.canRead(perm)),
      tap(isPermitted => (isPermitted ? isPermitted : this.feedback.notAllowed()))
);
```

}

And you can inherit into a guard service :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ParameterBaseGuard extends ParameterGuards implements CanLoad {
  constructor(public authService: AuthenticationService, public feedback: FeedbackService, public store: Store) {
    super(authService, feedback, store);
  }
  canLoad(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.fetchACLAndTestPermission('READ');
  }
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.canActivateRead();
  }
}
```